# Assigning form input value to java variable in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a scenario in which i am rendering a jsp page .One of my value is in my model Form entity.I am assigning it in one of my form input like below :

```
<s:hidden name="myModelName.myUserName"/>
```

I am trying to assign it to my java variable inside my jsp.I tried accessing the model directly like this

```
<%= String myName = myModelName.myUserName %>
```

But i get error message "myModelName cannot be resolved.I have then tried accessing from the hidden field.But i dont know how to use it.Anyway i need the value in java variable inside jsp for some reason.Anyone help me out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

assign your model property value to variable userName

```
<c:set var="userName" scope="session" value="${myModelName.myUserName}"/>
```

and then you can output it using this tag:

`<c:out value = "${userName}"/>`

You can read more about JSTL tags here: [Using JSTL tags](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm)

Hope this helps. Ask if you need anything else.